# Gson and Spring Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, gson, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring boot and spring actuator.
My project uses Gson's JsonElement extensively and all internal methods return JsonElements (which can either be JsonObject, JsonArray, etc)

Since, JsonElement is not a traditional POJO, Jackson has trouble serialising JsonElement.

So I configured the HttpMessageConvertor to use Gson instead of Jackson. After this, all my actuator apis (health, etc) seem to be messed up, since actuator relies heavily on Jackson annotations.

All I want is, to use Gson only for JsonElement and Jackson for all other Objects. Is this possible?

If not, how do I ensure Gson works seamlessly with actuator??

Gson Output

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": "DOWN",
    "description": ""
  },
  "details": {
    "discoveryComposite": {
      "status": {
        "code": "UP",
        "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client"
      },
      "details": {
        "discoveryClient": {
          "status": {
            "code": "UP",
            "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client"
          },
          "details": {
            "services": [
              "CM",
              "CM-DITTO",
              "consul",
              "couchbase",
              "rabbitmq"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Jackson Output

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "discoveryComposite": {
    "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client",
    "status": "UP",
    "discoveryClient": {
      "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client",
      "status": "UP",
      "services": [
        "CM",
        "CM-DITTO",
        "consul",
        "couchbase",
        "rabbitmq"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had pointed earlier, the issue was clearly because of some Jackson annotations used in actuator apis. Spring recommends using Jackson for json serailaisation so when gson is used it causes some problems.

The best solution is to write custom serialisers and deserialisers for Gson objects (JsonElement, JsonObject, etc) so jackson can appropriately serialise and deserialise the jsons.

[JsonMystique](https://github.com/balajeetm/json-mystique) library gives these custom serialisers/deserialisers out of the box.

[Full disclosure] Json Mystique is a library maintained by me

All you need to do is

1. include the jsonMystique [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.balajeetm%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json-mystique%22)
2. Add [JsonMystiqueConfig](https://github.com/balajeetm/json-mystique/wiki#usage-guide) to component scan
3. Thats it!!! JsonMystique by defaults registers a [module](https://github.com/balajeetm/json-mystique/blob/json-mystique-1.0.6/src/main/java/com/futuresight/util/mystique/lever/MystiqueModule.java) can serialise and deserialise Gson Elements

Now jackson will be able serialise Gson Elements. Thus, the below method signature for a RestController is completely valid

```
@RequestMapping(value = "query")
public DeferredResult<JsonElement> query(@RequestParam String host, @RequestBody JsonObject query) {

}
```

PS : If you do not want to import the entire library, please refer this [module](https://github.com/balajeetm/json-mystique/blob/json-mystique-1.0.6/src/main/java/com/futuresight/util/mystique/lever/MystiqueModule.java) to see the custom deserialisers